# Missing type IInAppBillingService

Tags: android, cordova, in-app-purchase

I use IInAppBillingService 3.0 and it gives me an error in labHelper.java:

```
The method asInterface(IBinder) from the type IInAppBillingService.Stub refers to the missing type IInAppBillingService
```

What's a problem?

Answer (score -1):

I think you picked the code from some were so this will come only because of improper package name.

So you have to just check package name of `com.android.vending.billing` and also check your manifest what package name you have mentioned.